# Stack Snippets are not shown properly in the review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, stack-snippets

Stack Snippets don't appear on posts in the review queue. Therefore, if a suggested edit adds/changes a snippet, there's no easy way for the reviewer to determine if the edit is valid. For an example, see [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5794826). Snippets should be allowed to run from the review queue.

Comment: This is probably due to the code needing time to propagate to all the servers + cache needs to expire. I was seeing the same problem, but for some reason 1 review had it working, but I refreshed the page, and it broke again.

Comment: @Populus interesting. I would suggest in the meantime that if you get a review that includes a stack snippet and you aren't able to run it, that you open the answer in a new tab to run it and make a decision, then return to the review to approve or reject it. It doesn't make sense to reject a useful edit just because the reviews UI isn't showing the snippet.

Comment: @nkinkle if the edit was to add the snippet, your suggestion doesn't help :P Because it won't show until after the edit has been approved!

Comment: @Populus that is a good point. I forgot that the suggested version is only shown to the user who suggested it. All the more reason for this bug to get fixed I suppose!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really helps if I actually *include* the Stack Snippets JavaScript file reference in the review queue. I have done so now and this should be working properly. Without the JavaScript, it was rendering an invisible div for snippets that were hidden by default. Should be good to go now.

Comment: Much better! Thank you.

Comment: @nhinkle thank *you* for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

They show up if you have the "markdown" diff option selected:

> [image: diff shown with "markdown" option selected]

They're hidden for "rendered output" diffs though. This same problem afflicts [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7220510/revisions):

> [image: revision history screenshot]

While it would be nice to have the snippet rendered in-place, even a placeholder that indicated it *existed* (and suggests switching to "markdown" view) would suffice here.

Comment: I did switch to markdown and didn't see anything. Is that just a result of residual caching issues?

Comment: OK so now I'm seeing that yes, you can see the `<!-- begin snippet -->` code, etc. but in none of the views (side-by-side markdown, side-by-side, or inline) does it show the actual runnable snippet. IMO it should.

Comment: I disagree! The "markdown" diff should show exactly what it does: the raw markdown. What if I want to know what someone changed within their 300-line snippet?

Comment: Right, the markdown view should show the raw markdown, that makes sense, but the rendered view (side-by-side) should show the runnable snippet.

Comment: I'm increasingly convinced that many reviewers have no idea what stack snippets are, see the changes, and think it's garbage being added to the post. There needs to be some kind of clear indicator that a stack snippet has been inserted and that it does something, so that it doesn't just look like somebody added a bunch of funky-looking HTML comments.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that this feature is *brand-spanking-new*, @nhinkle - it'll take a while for folks to become accustom to it.